# Modeless dialog keyboard handling (winapi)

Tags: winapi, dialog, keyboard

I've got an application with a main window which has a bunch of controls, including the spacebar, which is handled by a simple method called `onSpacebar()`. On top of that main window, I've got a persistent modeless dialog. 
I need the spacebar to behave the exact same way, regardless of whether the dialog has focus, or the main window has focus.

This dialog is backed by a DialogProc which looks something like this:

```
 BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
      switch(uMsg)
      {
      case WM_NOTIFY:
        std::cout<< "WM_NOTIFY" <<std::endl;
        switch(LOWORD(wParam))
        {
              // which component caused the message?
        case COMP_TREE:
              if(((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code == NM_DBLCLK){
                          onDoubleclk()
              }
              //...
        break;
        // other components...

        }
      break;
      case WM_CLOSE: 
          // the dialog can only be closed when the whole app is closed
          //EndDialog(hDlg, IDCANCEL); 
          return TRUE;
      case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage(0); 
          return TRUE;
      }
      return FALSE;
    }
```

From what I gather, I should call my `onSpacebar()` method from within the DialogProc, similarily how I handle the double click. I can see that `WM_NOTIFY` is received by the dialog when the spacebar is pressed (the phrase WM_NOTIFY is printed to cout), but I can't seem to differentiate the spacebar notification from the other numerous notifications the dialog receives.

Please, tell me how to recognize that the particular `WM_NOTIFY` was in response to a spacebar keypress.

Comment: You're `cout` message could probably be significantly more insightful if you tried printing *something* besides the name of the very message handler section you just put it in. Perhaps the `code` member of the NMHDR may shed some light onto your suspicion of a keyboard notification, especially if you actually *display* it so you know what it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`WM_NOTIFY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583.aspx) message is *not* the standard way that a window processes key press events. When a key is pressed, your window should be receiving [`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280.aspx), [`WM_KEYUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281.aspx), and possibly [`WM_CHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276.aspx) messages. `WM_NOTIFY` serves an entirely different purpose altogether: passing on a message from a common control to its parent window.

So the fact that you're receiving a `WM_NOTIFY` message in response to a key press is a fairly unusual thing, explainable when you understand how *focus* works (which is key to solving your ultimate question).

In Windows, only one window can be focused at a time, and the currently focused window is the one that receives *all* keyboard input. Thus, if a dialog box has the focus, it will receive key press notifications. If a *child* control on that dialog box has the focus, *it* (not its parent dialog) will receive key press notifications. And there is a focusable child control on a dialog box, it will *always* receive the focus in preference to its parent dialog, therefore it will also always receive key press notifications.

So the likely explanation for your curious `WM_NOTIFY` messages is that one of the [common controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169.aspx) on your dialog has the focus, it is receiving the space key press event, and after processing it, passing on a notification to its parent window (your dialog) in the form of a `WM_NOTIFY` message. As you might imagine, this is not a reliable method of detecting that the space bar has been pressed.

Instead, you need to figure out some way of trapping key press notifications *before* they get sent to the focused control. To do that, you'll need to modify your application's message loop to trap `WM_KEYDOWN` or `WM_KEYUP` messages *before* calling either [`DispatchMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934.aspx) or [`IsDialogMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498.aspx).

- If the key event corresponds to the space bar, you will call your `onSpacebar` function and indicate that the message was handled, preventing it from being passed on and processed by another window.
- If the key event does *not* correspond to the space bar, then you will need to handle the message as you usually would, ensuring that it *does* get passed on and processed by the other window.

Since this approach filters out space key presses at a global level, it solves both the problems of child controls on a dialog stealing the key press and the other modeless dialog. However, you do need to be careful because it's very easy to screw things up so that the user can't navigate your dialog using the keyboard at all.

More fundamentally, I think **your idea to handle presses of the *space bar* is fundamentally flawed**. The logic of certain common controls basically *requires* that they process presses of the space bar. For example, consider a textbox: if you filter out all presses of the space bar at a global level, the user will never be able to type a space in a textbox. If you insist on handling the space bar, you will need to check the focused control in your global handler, and if it's a textbox (or other common control that you wish to receive spaces), pass it on; otherwise, handle it yourself.

Honestly, what I'd do instead is choose a more unique key combination (like, I don't know, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) and set that up as an *accelerator*. Presumably, your global message loop is already processing accelerator keys by calling the [`TranslateAccelerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646373.aspx) function, so that would take care of all the dirty work for you. No code is even required—you'd do everything simply by editing the accelerators resource file in your project. The MSDN documentation on keyboard accelerators is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646337.aspx), but you'll probably have an easier time consulting your favorite book on Visual C++.

Comment: Actually, the app uses DirectInput in the main window to read all the keys, including the spacebar. The TreeView contains uneditable items, so I'd much rather just stick to that control.
With that said - I'm concerned whether or not the solution you suggest (trapping keypress notifications in the message loop) will break my DirectInput based main window.

Comment: I don't really know anything about DirectInput. I assumed from the tags that this question was strictly about Win32 programming. If DirectInput gives you a way to process keyboard events ***before*** the main message loop dispatches them for default handling, then it will probably work. That is why I took the time to explain what was happening, rather than just providing copy-and-pastable code. @sy.

Comment: I was sure there'd be a simple way to hook into the dialog box defaults - there usually is in Windows from what I gather. But I'm a newbie after all. That's why I didn't go into main window details. I didn't expect DirectInput to be relevant.
I've implemented my spacebar handling the way you suggested. It all works like a charm. Thank you very much! I have a followup question though: WM_KEYDOWN, WM_CHAR and WM_KEYUP messages are only received when the dialog has focus, when the main window has focus they're not. This is actually desirable in my case, but why is it so?

Comment: @sy. I don't know what you mean by "hook into the dialog box defaults". We're not dealing with the dialog box here, we're dealing with child controls *on* that dialog box who are processing the keyboard message before it ever gets passed to the dialog box parent. As for your follow-up question, the same reason applies. Those messages are only sent to the window that currently has the focus. That's a hard rule in Windows--only focused window gets notified of input. If that's a child window that doesn't process the input, it can pass it on to its parent until it finds a handler.